# race condition by using __block

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, objective-c-blocks, phasset

I have a list of PHAsset that I need to get their associated URL and do something with each URL. After all the assets are processed I need to perform another task. I try to use __block to count the assets that are processed, but it is not reliable due to race condition. Is there a better way of knowing when all the assets are processed?

```
    PHFetchResult* photosAsset = [PHAsset fetchAssetsInAssetCollection:collection options:fetchOptions2];
    __block int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < photosAsset.count; ++i) {
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:[photosAsset objectAtIndex:i] options:nil resultHandler:
         ^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
             NSURL *url = [(AVURLAsset *)avAsset URL];
             // then do something with the url here...

             ++count;
             NSLog(@"%d", count);
             if (count == photosAsset.count) {
                 NSLog(@"FINISHED!");
             }
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Maybe `dispatch_group_enter()`, `dispatch_group_leave()` and `dispatch_group_notify()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the solution based on @Larme's suggestion:

```
    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (int i = 0; i < photosAsset.count; ++i) {
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        [[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:[photosAsset objectAtIndex:i] options:nil resultHandler:
         ^(AVAsset *avAsset, AVAudioMix *audioMix, NSDictionary *info) {
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         }];
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
        NSLog(@"FINISHED!");
    });

    dispatch_release(group);
```